# Phoenix framework: how to run ecto.create with custom port?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I specify a **custom server port** for the `mix ecto.create` command in **Phoenix framework**?

I created a get-started project with the `mix phx.new hello` command.
I configured the database as follows in `hello\config\dev.exs` path,

```
config :hello, Hello.Repo,
   username: "postgres",
   password: "postgres",
   hostname: "localhost",
   database: "hello_dev",
   show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
   pool_size: 10
```

However, when I try to configure a **Postgres database** with the `mix ecto.create` command, I get the following error.

```
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
```

I use **5433** as the Postgres port (Note: it works with my spring java projects) because the default port of 5432 was not available in my local.

So in `hello\deps\ecto_sql\lib\ecto\adapters\postgres\connection.ex` path
I defined the default port in the path as follows,

```
@default_port 5433
```

but if I run the command again, it still tries to connect to 5432.

How do I get the command to **connect to 5433** instead of 5432?

Comment: Some word of advice: **Don't touch the code in your `/deps` folder!** These dependencies are managed by `mix` according to your project settings in `mix.exs`. If you want to customize a library: clone the library, make some adjustments and reference to a github repo or local path in your `deps` as mentioned [here](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run Ecto migrations on a custom port for Postgres, add the `port: <port_number>,` to the configuration. The additional options for the connection are in the [Ecto docs here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.html#module-options). So, to have it set to port `5433` instead of the default port `5432`, your configuration would look like this:

```
config :hello, Hello.Repo,
   username: "postgres",
   password: "postgres",
   hostname: "localhost",
   database: "hello_dev",
   port: 5433,
   show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
   pool_size: 10
```